How to keep the th and the first two cols of a table sticky while at the same time have a horizontal scrollbar on the table?
I need a table where the th (or thead) are sticky, and the first two columns are sticky, and there is a vertical scrollbar on the body, and a horizontal scrollbar on the table.
I have been able to achieve all of that, but not together.
When I have a sticky thead and first 2 cols, then the horizontal scrollbar is on the body.
When the horizontal scrollbar is on the table, the th and cols are not sticky.
Is it possible to achieve all these requirements, and if so, how?


body { 
  margin: 0;
}

header { 
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}


.sticky-col {
  position: sticky;
}

.first-col {
  left: 0px;
}

.second-col {
  left: 100px;
}

.table__wrapper { 
  /* width: calc(100vw - 25px); */
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.header__info-wrapper { 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.infoboard__wrapper { 
  display: flex;
  gap: 15px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.title { 
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}


table { 
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th { 
  padding: 10px;
}

table th:nth-child(1), 
table th:nth-child(2) { 
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 150px;
}

table th:not(:nth-child(1)):not(:nth-child(2)) {
  width: 300px;
}

th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0; 
  background-color: white; 
  border-bottom: none; 
}

thead:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.1px; 
  background-color: #ddd; 
  z-index: 2; 
}


a { 
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.basic__info { 
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
}

ul { 
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 0 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

ul li {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
}

li.planned__component-wrapper { 
  align-items: center;
}

.version__wrapper { 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

ifx-icon { 
  color: rgb(10, 130, 118);
}

.planned__icon { 
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  vertical-align: sub;
}
  <div class="table__wrapper">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="sticky-col first-col">Preview</th>
          <th class="sticky-col second-col">Component</th>
          <th>
            <div class="version__wrapper">
              <span>Version 1</span>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th>
            <div class="version__wrapper">
            <span>Version 2</span>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th>Version 3</th>
          <th>Version 4</th>
          <th>Version 5</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class=""></td>
          <td class="completed__component">
            <ifx-link href="" size="m" variant="bold">Accordion</ifx-link>
          </td>
          <td>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <span>
                  <ifx-icon icon="check12"></ifx-icon>
                </span>
                <span>Includes essential functionality such as expand/collapse behavior and minimal customization options</span>
              </li>
              <li>
                <span>
                  <ifx-icon icon="check12"></ifx-icon>
                </span>
                <span>Adheres to web standards</span>
              </li>
              <li>
                <span>
                  <ifx-icon icon="check12"></ifx-icon>
                </span>
                <span>Provides a simple and lightweight way to organize and display collapsible content</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </td>
          <td>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <span>
                  <ifx-icon icon="check12"></ifx-icon>
                </span>
                <span>Auto collapse feature</span>
              </li>
              <li>
                <span>
                  <ifx-icon icon="check12"></ifx-icon>
                </span>
                <span>Initial collapse feature</span>
              </li>
              <li>
                <span>
                  <ifx-icon icon="check12"></ifx-icon>
                </span>
                <span>React, Vue and Angular wrapper integration</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class=""></td>
          <td class="completed__component">
            <ifx-link href="" size="m" variant="bold">Alert</ifx-link>
          </td>
          <td>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <span>
                  <ifx-icon icon="check12"></ifx-icon>
                </span>
                <span>Provides a lightweight and customizable interface for presenting alerts, including options for different alert types (e.g., primary, success, danger, warning) and basic styling configurations</span>
              </li>
              <li>
                <span>
                  <ifx-icon icon="check12"></ifx-icon>
                </span>
                <span>Adheres to web standards</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </td>
          <td >
            <ul>
              <li>
                <span>
                  <ifx-icon icon="check12"></ifx-icon>
                </span>
                <span>Configurable close button</span>
              </li>
              <li>
                <span>
                  <ifx-icon icon="check12"></ifx-icon>
                </span>
                <span>Additional Info variant</span>
              </li>
              <li>
                <span>
                  <ifx-icon icon="check12"></ifx-icon>
                </span>
                <span>React, Vue and Angular wrapper integration</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td class="completed__component">
            <ifx-link href="" size="m" variant="bold">Badge</ifx-link>
          </td>
          <td >
            <ul>
              <li>
                <span>
                  <ifx-icon icon="check12"></ifx-icon>
                </span>
                <span>Offers simple customization options for displaying badges, allowing developers to indicate specific actions, statuses, or categories with visual cues</span>
              </li>
              <li>
                <span>
                  <ifx-icon icon="check12"></ifx-icon>
                </span>
                <span>Designed to seamlessly integrate with existing UI elements and adhere to web standards</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </td>
          <td >
            <ul>
              <li>
                <span>
                  <ifx-icon icon="check12"></ifx-icon>
                </span>
                <span>React, Vue and Angular wrapper integration</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td class="completed__component">
            <ifx-link href="" size="m" variant="bold">Breadcrumb</ifx-link>
          </td>
          <td >
            <ul>
              <li>
                <span>
                  <ifx-icon icon="check12"></ifx-icon>
                </span>
                <span>Provides a simple and customizable way to display a sequential trail of links or indicators,  representing the user's current location within a hierarchy of content</span>
              </li>
              <li>
                <span>
                  <ifx-icon icon="check12"></ifx-icon>
                </span>
                <span>Adheres to web standards</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </td>
          <td >
            <ul>
              <li>
                <span>
                  <ifx-icon icon="check12"></ifx-icon>
                </span>
                <span>Possibility to add an icon</span>
              </li>
              <li>
                <span>
                  <ifx-icon icon="check12"></ifx-icon>
                </span>
                <span>Incorporated dropdown-menu for individual items</span>
              </li>
              <li>
                <span>
                  <ifx-icon icon="check12"></ifx-icon>
                </span>
                <span>React, Vue and Angular wrapper integration</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>



NOTE: This does not provide a solution for when a horizontal scrollbar is required on the table.
